# Finding out the location of tweets downloaded by flume from twitter

Tags: java, twitter, location, geo, flume

I used some keywords and downloaded the tweets from twitter using flume.And the sample data looks like as follows

{"filter_level":"medium","contributors":null,"text":"Messi, Ozil, CR7 & Suarez Bertengger di Lamborghini t.co/SKk8xnnjl7","geo":null,"retweeted":false,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"possibly_sensitive":false,"truncated":false,"lang":"in","entities":{"symbols":[],"urls":[{"expanded_url":"dlvr.it/5XH5Vk","indices":[56,78],"display_url":"dlvr.it/5XH5Vk","url":"t.co/SKk8xnnjl7"}],"hashtags":[],"user_mentions":[]},"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"id":461450307856130048,"source":"http://dlvr.it\" rel=\"nofollow\">dlvr.it</a>","in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"favorited":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"retweet_count":0,"created_at":"Wed Apr 30 10:21:41 +0000 2014","in_reply_to_user_id":null,"favorite_count":0,"id_str":"461450307856130048","place":null,"user":{"location":"Subscribe Us","default_profile":false,"profile_background_tile":true,"statuses_count":158496,"lang":"en","profile_link_color":"006400","profile_banner_url":"pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/251586988/1368528690","id":251586988,"following":null,"protected":false,"favourites_count":1,"profile_text_color":"333333","description":"Latest Breaking News & Software.\r\n\r\nAkun ini dijual Rp150.000","verified":false,"contributors_enabled":false,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","name":"TOP NEWS","profile_background_color":"000000","created_at":"Sun Feb 13 12:54:44 +0000 2011","is_translation_enabled":false,"default_profile_image":false,"followers_count":37879,"profile_image_url_https":"pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/449966329588482048/Rb4azNrv_normal.jpeg","geo_enabled":false,"profile_background_image_url":"abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme14/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme14/bg.gif","follow_request_sent":null,"url":"google.com","utc_offset":25200,"time_zone":"Bangkok","notifications":null,"profile_use_background_image":true,"friends_count":10,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","screen_name":"7HotNews","id_str":"251586988","profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/449966329588482048/Rb4azNrv_normal.jpeg","listed_count":19,"is_translator":false},"coordinates":null}

Now I have to find out the location of the tweets from where it is tweeted.Also i came across some websites in which most answers that "geo" field in above json format gives the location of tweet.But it is null for my most of the tweets.
Please,anyone help me on this...I just rolling my head for two weeks....
Thanks in Advance,
RedDevil

Answer (score 0):

You have two types of locations: geo location and user location.
The user location is not reliables most of the time since users can type in anything they want.
The geo location is the best way for locating a tweet and as you have seen, most of the users do not enable their geo location.
You can use the few geo locations you have depending on what the purpose will be.